# What is Data Science and Machine Learning and what language mostly used to program?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, dataset, data

I am newbie in Data Science, Machine Learning and any related to data science but I want to try it. Unfortunately, googling makes it tedious and complicated so I hope to be answered by anybody who's kindhearted to share and enlighten me with it. Thank you so much.

Comment: I understand this question is opinionly answerable, so thank you @Mario and Leevo for the thoughts. Can I still mark a response as answer? Please advice. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

**Data Science** is a very broad expression, meaning: let's use a combination of statistics, math and computer science to make sense of data and produce predictive models that can generalize on data they have never seen. (Please refer to mainstream sources for a more thorough definintion).

**Machine Learning** is an approach to data analysis. It is based on splitting your data into (at least) train and test sets, training predictive models on the train set, and assessing their generalization capacity on the test set.

When it comes to choose the right language for DS / ML, please keep in mind that:

- R is the best language for econometrics and statistics
- Python is the best language for Deep Learning
- They are pretty much equivalent for non-deep ML

You can do anything you want with both of them, though. Choose based on your preferences and/or needs.

Answer (score 1):

ML is a subset of artificial intelligence (AI) that creates systems to learn and predict outcomes without manually programming a computer and is also known as **predictive analytics** or **statistical learning**. It is a set of algorithms and techniques focused to learn from data. This algorithms can be implemented by:

- Python:

  - The **scikit-learn** (additional packages of SciPy) exposes a concise and consistent interface to the common **machine learning** algorithms.
  - In case of **Deep Learning**, one of the most prominent and convenient libraries for Python in this field is **Keras**, which can function either on top of **TensorFlow** or **Theano**
- MATLAB especially using Deep Learning Toolbox
- JAVA or C++

The **Data** could be an organized collection of measures and/or classes; and **learning** means the ability to get information from data that would generalize to other sets of data. This last is what differences ML techniques from other statistical tools. They focus on the generalization aspect of the data analysis and not only in creating a model that works with the data at hand. A ML model is general, it is valid for new data points the model has never been exposed to.

Beside of that , there are another libraries and packages which pave the way to load, access, modify data, even plot them!